# How to send an explicit response with payload for a C2D (Cloud to Device) Azure IoT Hub message back to the initiator?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I am currently trying to implement some processing of C2D messages. So far sending a C2D message from an IoT Hub Function works like a charm and I'm receiving and processing the payload without any problems.

My problem however is, that on the initiating side I always get a positive ACK, even if I kill the IoT device while processing the command. It seems all documentation starts becoming a little vague as soon as it comes to responses to C2D messages. And I did read the related documents of the IoT Hub functionality multiple times ... Hope I didn't miss an essential part, but I doubt it.

So how can I explicitly send a response back to the initiator which also contains a payload?

I'm currently on the free demo-subscription as I'm doing my first steps with IoT Hub.

Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the device protocol used for connection to the IoT Hub? Note, that the device connected using the  **MQTT protocol** will generate automatically ACK  when the device is connected (and subscribed). In other words, the connected MQTT device can not handle a rejecting or abandoning C2D messages. I do recommend to use a postman to simulate https device for C2D messaging, see the REST APIs  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good place to start for any communication from cloud to the device is [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-c2d-guidance?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034). From what I can tell, in your situation, you might want to use a Direct Method rather than a C2D message. A C2D message is great for notifying the device, but as you experienced, there are no built-in features for responding to the message.

A direct method allows to send a request to a device, and for that device to respond to it. Both the request and response are allowed a 128 KB JSON payload, so you can use that on the device-side to send something back.

Update:
Like mentioned in the comments, you don't have a lot of influence on how to handle C2D messages from the device, other than accepting/rejecting it. Here's how you would reject a message using the C# Device SDK.

```cs
private async Task RejectSample()
{
    var deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("muchconnectionstring");
    var message = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync();
    // await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(message);
    await deviceClient.RejectAsync(message);
}
```

Comment: But in these documentation pages (especially here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-c2d) they say: "When you send a cloud-to-device message, the service can request the delivery of per-message feedback about the final state of that message. You do this by setting the iothub-ack application property in the cloud-to-device message that's being sent to one of the following four values:" ... and I set it to "full" ... does this mean that I have no control over the response and IoT Hub generates this as soon as the message is delivered?

Comment: When you set the `iothub-ack` property to `full` you will get a feedback message as soon as your C2D message is 'completed' by the device. It will also give you feedback messages if the message expired or the max delivery count has been reached. You're right to say that you have no control over the response, other than rejecting the message from the device side.

Comment: Are there any examples available how the device can actually reject the message?

Comment: There is now (see update). Most [samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-csharp/blob/master/iot-hub/Samples/device/MessageReceiveSample/MessageReceiveSample.cs) focus on the happy flow. But in the C# SDK it's as simple as having the client reject the message.

Comment: Yeah ... well probably as I'm using the GO version of the SDK from github.com/amenzhinsky/iothub ... that's probably just not supported.

Comment: Very possible! Perhaps you can add it or request the feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225336/discussion-between-matthijs-van-der-veer-and-christofer-dutz).